# What is the best way display full screen landscape videos and be able to swipe left or right to another video?

Tags: ios, swipe-gesture

I am currently dealing with some legacy code that displays a UIView like this:

[image]

This view shows a full screen video in landscape (portrait is not required). Overlaid onto the video is a small grey bar at the bottom with a label on it and a button to dismiss the view.

I would like to keep this functionality but add the ability for a user to swipe either left or right while the video is playing to show another full screen video while keeping the grey bar at the bottom. Each video can be stored within an array or dictionary.

My thoughts have been that I can add a pan gesture recognizer to the view but I am not sure how to deal with loading different videos presented in full screen like this. I'm sure it's possible to load each video into separate UIViews and swap what is displayed as the gesture is detected but I don't think this will provide a clean and animated transition between videos. It is important that the videos remain presented in full screen. What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a video going on in a MPMoviePlayerController* and on top have an invisible UIWindow* with windowLevel "UIWindowLevelStatusBar". Add the pan gesture to this UIWindow. And when you pan left or right, load new media url like this:

```
[player setContentURL:xyz];
[player play];
```

Resume playing from where you left with:

```
initialPlaybackTime = <last known position before swipe>
```

Comment: Would this be the best way for providing an animated transition between the videos though?

Comment: Well, for animation, replace the gesture recognizer with a UICollectionView*. Have this collection view's cell load the screenshots, so that when you slide, you would have the screenshots ready for pre-viewing and fade that out as the video starts playing. You may take this screenshot when you swipe out of the video thats already playing. This would give you ~.4 secs where you can stop/start the video.